# Create Folder structure on MAC using python

Tags: macos, python-2.7

In windows I run my tests and the framework will create the folders "C:\SAF\OutputData\Screenshots" and will save all the screenshots.

But, How can I create a equivalent Folder structure \SAF\OutputData\Screenshots on MAC using python?

Answer (score 1):

Same as in Windows, by using [`os.makedirs`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.makedirs). Note that:

- OSX uses forward slash (`/`) as the path delimiter. You can use [`os.path.join`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join) to make this part of your code platform-independent.
- While you can create a directory in the root of the filesystem, if you want to, it is discouraged. I am guessing that for your specific purpose you should use your home directory.